# Determining the Euler-Lagrange equations for a minimizataion problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm working on a problem in computer vision and I've ended up trying to minimize the functional 
$$\int \left[\lambda(S''(x))^2 + (f(x) - S(x))^2 \sum_k \delta (x - x_k)\right]dx$$

where $\lambda$ is a constant and, if it is relevant to you, $f(x)$ is the image plane. As an intermediary step it would be of great help if I could find the Euler-Lagrange equation for this optimization problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is equal to

$$
\int \lambda S\frac{d^4}{dx^4}S + (f-S)^2\sum_k \delta(x-x_k) dx
$$

which gives the E-L equation

$$
\lambda\frac{d^4}{dx^4}S
=
(f-S)\sum_k \delta(x-x_k).
$$

Also, integrating around some $x_k$ one gets

$$
\lambda \left( \frac{d^3S}{dx^3}(x_k^+)-\frac{d^3S}{dx^3}(x_k^-)\right)=f(x_k)-S(x_k)
$$
which shows that the third derivative of $S$ is discontinuous.

Comment: Any chance for assistance here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066495/minimization-of-variational-total-variation-tv-deblurring